# Okta - Bulk Import New Users With Default Password Via CVS

Tags: okta, okta-api

Is there a way to bulk import new users into Okta and have all their passwords be default set.  Example upload 50 users with first name, last name, email, salesforce id, and a default password of 123QWEasd!

I read this https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/users-groups-profiles/usgp-import-users-csv.htm, but I don't think you can set the password.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to look into scripting this and just using the [Users API endpoint](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#create-user-with-password) to loop through your list of users and create the user with the default password. ]

You can also check out the [Okta Management SDKs](https://github.com/okta/?q=%22okta-sdk-%22&type=&language=) to help format the API call if you expect that you will need to do this again, otherwise a simple script or even something like the Postman Runner tool should suffice